# Why does this code produce an infinite loop?

Tags: dynamic, warning-messages, files-and-directories

I can't understand the way this code behaves and suspect that is because of some unrecognized reasons of general interest.  Otherwise, I apologize and will retire the question.

In `$UserBaseDirectory` the file `init.m` calls an initialization package:

```
Needs[
"UserInitialization`",
"E:\\Mathematica\\UserInitialization\\UserInitialization.m"
];
```

In `UserInitialization.m` a function performs a check about the folders that are supposed to exist:

```
systemFoldersList={....};
check = TrueQ @@ And @@ DirectoryQ /@ systemFoldersList;

If[check
,Null
,MessageDialog["ERROR : Some folder are missing !"];
Quit[];
];
```

and is intended to shout a warning and quit the kernel if one of them is missing.

Instead, when it doesn't find a folder it happens that:

1. the `MessageDialog` is fired over and over again
2. the **end process** button in Windows Task Manager is grayed out
3. the only way to quit Mathematica is from the command prompt, using taskkill /F /IM Mathematica.exe

As far I see, there is no obvious explanation.
Why this code produces an infinite loop ?

Comment: You never know what happens in the back, maybe after quit, a paclet manager or whatever is called  by FrontEnd, kernel is starting and you have your loop. Dynamic elements or Initializations may prompt it to start too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Please, can you provide further readings about that ?

Comment: I don't know any :/